# Effect of double quotes in macOS Command Line?

Tags: macos, command-line

I’m trying to execute a shell command that deletes the content of the folder. This was executed on macOS Catalina.

This command works:

```
rm -r /path/folder/*
```

But this won’t work:

```
rm -r “/path/folder/*”
```

I wonder what is the effect of those quotes. The path changes because it is executed from my program. I added quotes in the path to make up for spaces in the path if it exists. Then I tested it in actual command line to check and it behaves like that.

Comment: The quoting rules between Bash and Zsh are slightly different. If your system was upgraded crom an earlier macOS version, yon could have Bash; starting with Catalina, the default interactive shell for new users is (unfortunately) Zsh.

Comment: Your question has curly "typographers' quotes" which are simply literal characters to the shell. (But you probably don't have a directory named `“` so the wildcard won't match if this is correctly transcribed.) If you meant to put actual stright ASCII double quotes, please [edit] to fix (and otherwise probably edit to clarify that this is actually using curly quotes on purpose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes are to *block-escape* paths containing space characters.

In case of an asterisk as a wildcard you have to keep the asterisk out of the block

```
rm -r "/path/my great folder"/*
```

An alternative is to escape each space character with a backslash.

```
rm -r /path/my\ great\ folder/*
```